# Typescript: How to extract return type out of generic function type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to extract the return type of generic function type? Here is an example what I have in mind.

```
type Generic = <T = void>() => T[] | string
type Return = ReturnType<Generic<number>>; //Error Type 'Generic' is not generic.
//Expecting to get 'number[] | string' type
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=44&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxlAvFAPAFSygDcB7FAEwD4AKASi0qjwG0BdKAHygGdhV4A5gChQkKACUIwAK5J4hSTLl5wEHHESo0OeNIC2AI2SVKAbigB6CwFEkSEkiaqoAcg3J0LqCm5R4JYCgBBA80ADohK2sAD0g0YBRBKGASIKlXXUNkNk4ePkSBL1EIISEgA)

Comment: type Generic<T> = <T = void>() => T[] | string

Comment: `type Generic = <T = void>() => T[] | string` is from third party library declarations file and I don't have access to modify it. All I can get is `<T = void>() => T[] | string` type. Is there a way to do this without type modification?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of hacky but should do:

```typescript
type Generic = <T = void>() => T[] | string
type ReplaceUnknown<T, B> = T extends unknown[] ? B[] : T

type Return = ReplaceUnknown<ReturnType<Generic>, number>
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZ80Kw)